# What's an alternative for the deprecated setProps() in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mocha.js

I just upgraded my project's React version to 13.3 and `setProps()` is no longer working.  I'm using it in this Mocha test and I'm not sure how to rewrite it now.  What are my options?

```
it('reloads search results when props change ', function() {
    var loadResultsSpy = sinon.spy(searchView, 'loadSearchResults');
    var newProps = {searchBy: 'foo', searchTerm: 'bar'};
    searchView.setProps(newProps);
    expect(loadResultsSpy.calledWith(newProps.searchBy, newProps.searchTerm)).toBe(true);
  });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the most general case, React recommends just re-rending the top-level component, which essentially just updates the props if the new render is of the same component type. Since `TestUtils.renderIntoDocument` is simply a shortcut for [creating a DOM node and doing a regular render into it](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/ea964e760c728430f577d5b778bbac1bc6c696f2/src/test/ReactTestUtils.js#L74-83), something like this will work (I'm making some assumptions about the setup of your tests):

```
var searchView, div;

beforeEach(function() {
  var comp = <SearchView searchBy="baz" searchTerm="quix" />;
  div = document.createElement('div');
  searchView = React.render(comp, div);
});

it('reloads search results when props change', function() {
  var loadResultsSpy = sinon.spy(searchView, 'loadSearchResults');
  var comp = <SearchView searchBy="foo" searchTerm="bar" />;
  React.render(comp, div);
  expect(loadResultsSpy.calledWith("foo", "bar")).toBe(true);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this. On newer versions of React, one will need `ReactDOM.render` instead of `React.render`.